# Learn how to create LaTeX styles?

Tags: latex, coding-style

How can I learn how to create LaTeX styles?

The normal way when creating a LaTeX document is to start with something like.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
```

And that seems to call a .cls (and a .sty) file like letter.cls, 
that is controlling the actual layout of the document.

Is there a good way to learn how to create this type of "latex style files"?
Has someone created a howto, step-by-step or simply a good manual on the topic?

Thanks
Johan

---

**update**:

I guess that tex.stackexchange.com is the answer on how to continue learning LaTeX.
With questions like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials

Comment: That's the reason there's a new Tex Q&A site! http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As far as I know, LaTeX is about document layout and not programming. Can you please explain the programming angle of your question, as I don't see it.

Comment: @Oded TeX/LaTeX is turing complete, and it has been well established that it is allowed in SO.

Comment: @Amir Rachum - I don't doubt that. It's just that this question is about creating styles and doesn't have a programming aspect to it _at all_.

Comment: @Oded: IMO, creating styles is very much programming. However, as tex.stackexchange gathers momentum, I imagine that all of these questions will find their way over there without having to be "evicted from SO"

Comment: @Amir Rachum, I did not know about tex.stackexchange.com. Sounds like a better forum for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two good papers in the PracTeX journal:

- [Minutes in Less Than Hours: Using LaTeX Resources](http://tutex.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-4/hefferon/) by Jim Hefferon,
- [Rolling your own Document Class](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/flynn/) by Peter Flynn.

A very useful resource is [LATEX2e for class and package writers](http://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide).

This question is also discussed here: [Style/class tutorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials). You are kindly invited to use the links there and perhaps join the discussion there if you like.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but *may* give you a better return on the time invested, depending on how you see your future use of LaTeX.

[Memoir](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) for documents, [Beamer](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for presentations.

> "All the LaTeX styles you'll ever
>   need!"

Comment: http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf ???

Comment: Just corrected; sorry for the careless linking.